# How could I solve - Failed to download mysql connector .jar... Received fatal alert: protocol_version?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, phpstorm

[image: Screenshot of the error on phpStorm]I am trying to download the missing driver files on phpStorm for mySQL. I keep getting this error:

`Failed to download 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.47/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar': Received fatal alert: protocol_version`

I haven't found any solutions to this problem online. Would really appreciate if someone could let me know how I could achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: are you running some maven command? Please update the question with same

Comment: @tryingToLearn No, I am not. Please check the screenshot, updated it just now. That's what it looks like.

Comment: which version of java are you using?

Comment: ```openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 12.0.2+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)``` @tryingToLearn

Answer (score -1):

I recommend taking a look in IDE log files to see if they may have additional details as to why the download is failing.

Use Java 8 and also It needs to enable `TLS 1.2` protocol with Java property in the command line.

```
mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 install
```

Additionally, you can download the file and install them manually.

I couldn't find any official JetBrains MySQL driver repo page, but I found some old URLs that are official and work,

http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar
http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar

And also you can get all the old to latest MySQL Connectors versions from the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).

**PS:** To know how to add an external MySQL Connector library to [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-database-connections.html#add-a-user-driver-to-an-existing).